# SAS changing null to ''

Tags: export, sas, delimiter

I'm trying to export a dataset into a txt file using ; as the delimiter, the dataset has lots of null numeric and char values, I want to replace all those values to '' (no spaces here).

I tried using the code below to do this but it seems SAS will change '' to ' ' (one blank)

```
if missing(VAR22) then VAR22='' ;
put VAR22 $ @;
```

Full code:

```
data _null_;
set  lib.TABLE;                                  
file "/home/user/file.txt" delimiter=';';
format VAR1 $1. ;
format VAR2 $8. ;
format VAR3 $3. ;
format VAR4 $6. ;
format VAR5 $9. ;
format VAR6 $2. ;
format VAR7 $1. ;
format VAR8 $4. ;
format VAR9 $1. ;
format VAR10 $1. ;
format VAR11 BEST12.;
format VAR12 NUMX13.2;
format VAR13 BEST12.;
format VAR14 NUMX13.2;
format VAR15 $1. ;
format VAR16 $2. ;
format VAR17 $3. ;
format VAR18 $3. ;
format VAR19 $4. ;
format VAR20 $20. ;
format VAR21 $1. ;
format VAR22 $1. ;

if missing(VAR1) then VAR1='' ;
put VAR1 $ @; 
put VAR2 $ @;
put VAR3 $ @;
put VAR4 $ @;
put VAR5 $ @;
put VAR6 $ @;
put VAR7 $ @;
put VAR8 $ @;
put VAR9 $ @;
if missing(VAR10) then VAR10='' ;
put VAR10 @;
put VAR11 @;
put VAR12 @;
put VAR13 @;
put VAR14 @;
put VAR15 $ @;
put VAR16 $ @;
put VAR17 $ @;
put VAR18 $ @;
put VAR20 $ @;
put VAR19 $ @;
put VAR21 $ @;
if missing(VAR22) then VAR22='' ;
put VAR22 $ @; 
put ;
run;
```

I've also tried to use the options missing='', but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: By '' I mean NOTHING, no quotes and no spaces, basically an empty char

Comment: The problem with this code is that when you say `if missing(VAR1) then VAR1='' ;` .  Assume VAR1 is missing, then VAR1 gets overwritten by the null character.  SAS stores the null character (for character type variables) as a single blank, so you are back where you started.

Comment: Yeah you're right! I tried to use: 
put '' @ ; 

But it sends a single quote to the text file, is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you look at example 2 on this page http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002257076.htm you may be able to concatate all your variables into a single string of text (in the format you want, including delimeters) and just export it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS does not support null strings; any number of spaces in a character variable with no other character is by definition a character missing.  All strings are padded to their full length (whatever is allocated for that entire column) with '20'x (normal space character), and cannot be zero length.

Depending on what you are doing with these variables, there are ways to get them to not affect your downstream processes.  For example, `trimn` will return a zero length string if the variable is all spaces; so `var0=trimn(var1)||trimn(var2)||trimn(var3)` will return `var1||var3` if var2 has only spaces.

If you are doing concatenation, even better is to use `cats` instead of the `||` operator, as it automatically removes spaces (including removing all spaces from a missing string).  The resulting variable must contain spaces, but the components have theirs removed.

The idea of concatenating strings together is also a good one.  Unfortunately I don't think `CATX` works with completely missing strings, but you could do this perhaps in a macro or something.

```
data _null_;
set test;
file "c:\temp\test.csv";
outvar = catt(trimn(x1),';',trimn(x2),';',trimn(x3));
put outvar;
run;
```

Finally, if you're going to be interfacing with another DBMS that does have the concept of a null string, there may be a better solution; post those details.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
data one;
   length VAR1-VAR4 $1;
   input VAR1-VAR4;
   datalines;
A B C D
E . F G
H . . J
;
run;

data two;
   set one;
   SP=';';
   test1=trim(left(VAR1)) || sp || trim(left(VAR2)) || sp || trim(left(VAR3)) || sp || 
      trim(left(VAR4));
   test1 = compress(test1,' ');
run;

proc print data=two;
run;
```

I suggest you build a simple macro to run through all your VAR1 -- VARXX.

If you look at the variable test1 you can see thats what you want to output to your text file.

Note, If any of your char variables already contain spaces as part of thier actual value, this code will remove them.  If that is an issue, let me know and i can fix it.

Comment: TRIMN will work for what you want - it returns a null string instead of using that extra COMPRESS line.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, it wasn't exactly what I needed but It worked for other stuff I'm doing here!